# Error when trying to add 2 (or even just 1) images to a question

Tags: support, status-completed

I'm new to the SE site, and have a reputation of 1.  When I wrote my first question a few days ago, I added 2 small map/feature images to the question.  When I tried to post the question, I got an error saying I needed a rep of at least 10 to add "more than 2 images." So I removed 1 of the 2 images and tried posting again.  Same error.

Can someone tell me what I may have done wrong there?

Comment: It's not easy being new, I remember the same thing happened when I started. I know you can't add images but you can add hyperlinks.. if you have a google drive, dropbox or similar you could put your images there and then provide a link to them. As a courtesy, when doing so explain in your question that you *had* to do it this way due to lack of rep; a lot of users will not, or can not, follow links but perhaps someone with enough rep will edit them into your question for the benefit of all.

Comment: I don't have any link info to back it up, but a couple of days ago I believe there were some Imgur issues (Imgur is the image service that Stack Exchange uses).  I was not able to add images to an answer I was editing.  maybe you hit the same issue I did.

Comment: If you would like to post a link to the image hosted somewhere else into your question or a comment, I will be happy to add the image into your question (as will many other users).  Or try again to add your image to see if it will let you now

Answer (score 5):

The advice in the [comment by @MichaelMiles-Stimson](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/error-when-trying-to-add-2-or-even-just-1-images-to-a-question/4604#comment8402_4603) is good:

> I know you can't add images but you can add hyperlinks.. if you have a
>   google drive, dropbox or similar you could put your images there and
>   then provide a link to them. As a courtesy, when doing so explain in
>   your question that you had to do it this way due to lack of rep; a lot
>   of users will not, or can not, follow links but perhaps someone with
>   enough rep will edit them into your question for the benefit of all.

and this is reinforced by [Reputation 10 to post images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183926/215590) on Meta Stack Exchange (which is for Q&As generic to all sites).